# C++ algorithm for 2 lines with same length

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can't find good way to solve such a problem:
we have 5 <= k <= 50 segments with length from 1 to 1000 units.
Program has to build two pillars with the same length from these segments.
Program has to find a maximum possible length of the pillars.

For example:
5 segments with length: 1 5 2 3 4
correct solution is: 1st pillar 2+5=7 and 2nd pillar 3+4=7.

How would you deal with that?

Comment: Looks like a contest question

Comment: This is not the right way to ask a question here. But hint: For every digit, get the sum of it with _all the rest, individually_. You will get a matrix. Find max in the whole matrix. check if you have the founded max somewhere else, if not, take the **2nd** max of the whole matrix and recheck for it; till you find a "match"

Comment: Do you sum just two numbers, or more? More would make the problem real hard I think. Typical school exercise :)

Comment: Honestly sounds like repeated application of subset sum problem. May be NP-Complete.

Comment: Yes, you can take more than two segments. In this case: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, the correct solution can be: 1st: 4+8+9=21 and 2nd: 3+5+6+7=21

Comment: @FirstStep: Doesn't that assume a pillar will only consist of 2 segments?

Comment: Unfortunately not :)

Comment: In the case of  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, you can leave out 1 and reach 22 with 2 3 8 9 and 4 5 6 7. This is easy to find because the numbers are consecutive.

Comment: @neutrino: Likely this is a class exercise and there is some information you are omitting that would make this problem a bit easier to solve asymptotically. A brute force solution would take O(2^N), and with N = 50, that may take quite some time. Is there anything you left out?

Comment: Ok, but this is only the example. Numbers are random (from 1 to 1000 units). This is all information I got, sorry.

Comment: @LorenzoGatti: Sorted numbers that increase by 1 would indeed make the problem easier, but we cannot assume such things unless the OP edits the question to say as much :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem sounds like what you are wanting to do. The Wikipedia article has a couple of algorithms.  Also https://www.quora.com/Dynamic-Programming-DP-Where-can-I-find-a-good-link-to-understand-the-subset-sum-problem has some additional answers on subset sum.

Comment: @Richard Chambers: looks this is a way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has an article on [the Partition Problem in Computer Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) whose lead sounds like what you are wanting to do.

> In computer science, the partition problem (or number partitioning[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem))
>   is the task of deciding whether a given multiset S of positive
>   integers can be partitioned into two subsets S1 and S2 such that the
>   sum of the numbers in S1 equals the sum of the numbers in S2. Although
>   the partition problem is NP-complete, there is a pseudo-polynomial
>   time dynamic programming solution, and there are heuristics that solve
>   the problem in many instances, either optimally or approximately. For
>   this reason, it has been called "the easiest NP-hard problem".

There are references to several different algorithms to provide solutions.

See also the following.

[Is partitioning an array into halves with equal sums P or NP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292162/partition-problem)

[3-PARTITION problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803668/3-partition-problem)

[custom partition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779924/custom-partition-problem)

[C++ Elegant solution to partition problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321997/c-elegant-solution-to-partition-problem)

Answer (score 0):

It's some bizarre code, but does it's job.
(Note, no optimizations were applied to this code, might run slow,
works best for small sets - `x!` complexity)

```
template<template<typename...> class Set = std::vector,
         template<typename...> class Pair = std::pair,
         template<typename...> class Cont,
         typename... Ts>
inline Set<Cont<Pair<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type, size_t>>> all_subsets(const Cont<Ts...>& cont)
{
    Set<Cont<Pair<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type, size_t>>> all_subsets;
    Cont<Pair<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type, size_t>> empty;
    all_subsets.push_back(empty);

    for(auto it1 = cont.begin(); it1 != cont.end(); ++it1)
    {
        Set<Cont<Pair<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type, size_t>>> temp_subset = all_subsets;
        for(auto& it2 : temp_subset)
            it2.push_back({*it1, std::distance(cont.begin(), it1)});
        for(const auto& it2 : temp_subset)
            all_subsets.push_back(it2);
    }
    return all_subsets;
}

template<template<typename...> class Cont,
         typename... Ts>
inline bool intersects_by_second(const Cont<Ts...>& first,  const Cont<Ts...>& second)
{
    for(auto it1 : first)
        for(auto it2 : second)
            if(it1 == it2)
                return true;
    return false;
}

template<template<typename...> class Cont,
         typename... Ts>
inline Cont<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type::first_type> make_vector_of_firsts(const Cont<Ts...> cont)
{
    Cont<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type::first_type> result;
    for(const auto& it : cont)
        result.push_back(it.first);
    return result;
}

template<template<typename...> class Cont,
         typename... Ts>
inline Cont<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type::second_type> make_vector_of_seconds(const Cont<Ts...> cont)
{
    Cont<typename Cont<Ts...>::value_type::second_type> result;
    for(const auto& it : cont)
        result.push_back(it.second);
    return result;
}

template<template<typename...> class Bag = std::vector,
         template<typename...> class Pair = std::pair,
         template<typename...> class Cont,
         typename... Ts>
inline Bag<Pair<Cont<Ts...>, Cont<Ts...>>> full_sum_partition(const Cont<Ts...>& cont)
{
    auto subsets = all_subsets(cont);

    Bag<Pair<Cont<Ts...>, Cont<Ts...>>> result;

    for(auto it1 : subsets)
        for(auto it2 : subsets)
        {
            auto it1_firsts = make_vector_of_firsts(it1);
            auto it2_firsts = make_vector_of_firsts(it2);
            if(std::accumulate(it1_firsts.begin(), it1_firsts.end(), 0)
               ==
               std::accumulate(it2_firsts.begin(), it2_firsts.end(), 0))
            {
                if(intersects_by_second(it1, it2)
                   ||
                   it1.size() != it2.size())
                    continue;
                result.push_back(Pair<Cont<Ts...>, Cont<Ts...>>
                                 (it1_firsts,
                                  it2_firsts));
            }
        }
    return result;
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64};
    auto result = full_sum_partition(vec);

    for(const auto& x : result)
        std::cout << x << " with sum " << std::accumulate(x.first.begin(),
                                                          x.first.end(),
                                                          0) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
([], []) with sum 0
([1, 25, 36], [4, 9, 49]) with sum 62
([16, 25, 36], [4, 9, 64]) with sum 77
([4, 9, 49], [1, 25, 36]) with sum 62
([16, 49], [1, 64]) with sum 65
([4, 36, 49], [9, 16, 64]) with sum 89
([1, 16, 36, 49], [4, 9, 25, 64]) with sum 102
([1, 64], [16, 49]) with sum 65
([4, 9, 64], [16, 25, 36]) with sum 77
([9, 16, 64], [4, 36, 49]) with sum 89
([4, 9, 25, 64], [1, 16, 36, 49]) with sum 102
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Also note that I have overloaded operator << for various containers, this output will work only with my additional files. Here is version for everyone
(Just printing part):

```
for(const auto& x : result)
{
    size_t i=0;
    std::cout << "([";
    for(i=0; i< x.first.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << x.first[i] << "],"[(i<x.first.size()-1)];
    if(i==0)
        std::cout << ']';
    std::cout << ",[";
    for(i=0; i< x.second.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << x.second[i] << "],"[(i<x.first.size()-1)];
    if(i==0)
        std::cout << ']';
    std::cout << ')'
              << " with sum " << std::accumulate(x.first.begin(),
                                                x.first.end(),
                                                0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Factorial complexity? This would be worse than 2^n. With an input of 50, which OP might see, the universe will end before computation completes.

Comment: @AndyG True, but I don't have required theory knowledge to implement any faster version. I know that everything more complex than x^{2,3,4...} is extremely bad (like this code :) )

Comment: That's fair. For reference, though, a brute force solution that computes all possible combinations, and then iterates until it finds two that are the same and maximal would only be O(2^N) which is less than N!. I didn't actually parse your code, so I don't know if this is what your real complexity is. I suggest you look into Karps 21 NP-Complete problems, and maybe dig a little bit into How to prove a problem is NP-Complete by reduction if you want to learn more.